# Candle stand modeling question

Tags: modeling

[image]

How to model this stand? I've tried to use curve, but it doesn't look right.[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** Probably much easier since 2.8 with the new *Mirror "Bisect"* option

Former answer:

- Create a cylinder (12 vertices), put its origin to its bottom.
- Duplicate it with a <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>.
- Rotate the copy 120° on the Y axis (or whatever angle).
- Duplicate the second cylinder and rotate it 120° on the Z axis.
- Again create a fourth cylinder and rotate it 120°.
- Now use some *Boolean* modifiers to merge these 4 cylinder.
- Remove doubles to make the final object clean. You should not have any vertices inside your mesh but if it happened just delete them.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (*Convert to Geometry*) Delete bad intersecting faces, rebuild (re model). There´s no way around to bypass this bad geometry issue you have with the skin modifier since there´s not the necessary number of polygons between intersections, not even if you scale them.

Convert the mesh. Recreate patches to the leg.

Comment: Please don't ask for upvotes in your posts, and eliminate any extraneous text not part of the answer. If you must do it in the comments